# Strapi Plugin Route Default Permission

Tags: strapi

I am building a plugin for Strapi with several routes, for example:

```
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/preAnalyzeImportFile",
      "handler": "ImportConfig.preAnalyzeImportFile",
      "config": {
        "policies": ["global.isAuthenticated"]
      }
    }
```

When the plugin is installed, any authenticated user should be able to use the new routes. I can change the permissions manually so that the routes work, but that should not be a required workflow to use the plugin.

How do I set default permissions for plugin routes?

Answer (score 2):

There is no documentation about how to do it in Strapi but.

Here is how to use `permissions` function to get, create, update permissions `strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].models.permission`. So how to deal with.

You will have to write your code in the `./config/function/bootstrap.js`.
This code is executed every time your server start.

To create your permission you will have to find the role you want to update (with the type `authenticated`) `strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].models.role.find`.

When you have the id of the role you will create a permission with `strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].models.permission.create`

Object params to send:

- type: will be the name of your plugin
- controller: will be the name of your controller `importconfig` in your case
- action: the name of the function `preanalyzeimportfile` in your case
- enabled: true
- role: the role id you want to apply this policy

Comment: Is there a way to run once when the plugin is installed?

Comment: You can't use a `post-install` script because you will not have access to the `strapi` variable.

You will have to check it on every start.

But a solution can be to add a config file in your plugin and to set a `init` attribute to false by default, and update it to true when your create your permissions for the first time.

Comment: Great - I will do that. I didn't see an example of using custom config from plugins - can you point me to docs or a plugin that uses it's own config (some other config than routes/queries/functions/policies)?

Comment: Here for the GraphQL plugin https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-plugin-graphql/config/settings.json

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `strapi.store` to flag whether init has run?

Comment: #2: I am getting "strapi.plugins.users-permissions.models.role.find is not a function". I'm always confused about whether models.etc. is something from Strapi or a mongoose or bookshelf model directly or what.

Comment: #3 This seems okay: `await strapi
    .query('role', 'users-permissions')
    .findOne({ type: 'authenticated' })`

Comment: Ho yes you can use the `core store` if you want to store if the setup of your plugin is done or not.
You will find documentation of the usage of this API here https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/configurations/configurations.html#database-configuration

Comment: I'm getting strapi.plugins.users-permissions.models.permission.create is not a function. Does this method still work?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you set permissions.

```js
// In your bootstrap.js file
'use strict';
module.exports = async () => {

    const authenticated = await strapi.query('role', 'users-permissions').findOne({ type: 'authenticated' });
    authenticated.permissions.forEach(permission => {

        if (permission.type === 'application'){ // Whatever permissions you want to change
            let newPermission = permission;
            newPermission.enabled = true; // Editing permission as needed

            strapi.query('permission', 'users-permissions').update( { id: newPermission.id }, newPermission ); // Updating Strapi with the permission
        }
    });
    return;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For Strapi version `3.0.0-beta.x` & later,

**[Create a global policy](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/concepts/policies.html#how-to-create-a-policy)**

Create a JavaScript file named `isAuthenticated.js` in `./config/policies/`

Path: `./config/policies/isAuthenticated.js`

```
module.exports = async (ctx, next) => {
  if (ctx.state.user) {
    // Go to next policy or will reach the controller's action.
    return await next();
}

  ctx.unauthorized(`You're not logged in!`);
};
```

Here, we are verifying that a session is open. If it is the case, we call the `next()` method that will execute the next policy or controller's action. Otherwise, a 401 error is returned.

**[Use the policy in your routes](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/concepts/policies.html#usage)**

```
 {
   "method": "GET",
   "path": "/preAnalyzeImportFile",
   "handler": "ImportConfig.preAnalyzeImportFile",
   "config": {
     "policies": ["global::isAuthenticated"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to set plugins permissions programatically in Strapi v4:

```
  const wantedPermission =await strapi
   .query("plugin::users-permissions.permission")
   .findOne({where: {action: "api::testssd.testssd.find"}});

  const publicRole = await strapi
  .query('plugin::users-permissions.role')
  .findOne({where: {type: "public"}, populate: ['users', 'permissions']});

  //add the permission to the public role in the db if not already present
  if (!publicRole.permissions.some(permission => permission.action == "api::testssd.testssd.find")) {
    publicRole.permissions.push(wantedPermission);
    await strapi.query('plugin::users-permissions.role').update({
       where: {id: publicRole.id},
      data: {permissions: publicRole.permissions},
    });
  }
```